# Como remover a quebra de linha automática ao adicionar uma imagem no Word via Python DOCX?

Tags: python

Sempre que colocamos uma **nova imagem** no word via **DOCX** ela cria um parágrafo pra si.

gostaria de saber se há uma forma de **cancelar** essa ação natural do múdulo **DOCX** para que eu possa colocar uma imagem ao lado da outra (como na imagem)?

```
from docx import Document
import os

document = Document()

temporary_folder = r'C:\Users\wjunior.DIGICORNER\Desktop\imagens aqui\temporary_folder'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(temporary_folder):
    for file in files:
        document.add_picture(os.path.join(temporary_folder, file))      
        
document.save('demonstracao.docx')
```

> Sendo essa temporary_folder uma pasta com imagens qualquer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Gente, to fazendo uma pergunta que atende tudo que pedem ali e mesmo assim estão cancelando...

Comment: pergunta direta, simples, com o que tentei para resolver, até imagem coloquei... me ajuda aí (pfvor)

Comment: Não duplique as perguntas https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/547237/como-editar-imagens-para-word-doc-no-python-docxpillow . A pergunta original foi fechada pois é assim que, em geral, o leitor da pergunta a enxerga https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/docx#main.py , só um código sem sentido que gera erros. A ideia do [mcve] é que o leitor copie e cole o código e esteja inserido na mesma situação descrita na pergunta para que então possa investigar quais as causas do problema. Nesse caso o leitor ainda terá que descobrir o porque o exemplo não se comporta como o descrito na pergunta.

Comment: Veja o [Checklist de perguntas do Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8496/137387), [FAQ da Comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699) e [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/137387)

Comment: Entendi @augusto

Comment: Dupliquei a pergunta pois não tive nem tempo de tentar editar para melhorá-la, nem recebi uma crítica que me explique aonde tá errada a minha pergunta. mas me desculpe por isso.

Comment: Não precisa se desculpar, esse é ciclo de vida das perguntas. O ciclo criar, avaliar, fechar, aprimorar, reavaliar e abrir de perguntas deveria ser algo normal, mas infelizmente as pessoas entendem uma critica negativa ou um fechamento como algo pessoal e não um caminho em busca da resposta. Vou testar o seu código agora mas ainda tenho algumas ressalvas, vou ter que coletar imagens para teste mas isso e de menos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Entendendo imagens e outras formas**
> Conceitualmente, os documentos do Word têm duas camadas , uma camada de texto
> e uma camada
> de desenho . Na camada de texto, os objetos de texto fluem da esquerda
> para a direita e de cima para baixo, iniciando uma nova página quando
> a anterior for preenchida. Na camada de desenho, objetos de desenho,
> chamados de formas , são colocados em posições arbitrárias. Às vezes,
> eles são chamados de formas flutuantes.
>
> Uma imagem é uma forma que pode aparecer no texto ou na camada de
> desenho. Quando aparece na camada de texto, é chamado de forma
> embutida ou, mais especificamente, de imagem embutida .
>
> As formas inline são tratadas como um caractere de texto grande (um
> glifo de caractere ). A altura da linha é aumentada para acomodar a
> forma e a forma é quebrada em uma linha na qual caberá na largura,
> assim como o texto. Inserir texto na frente dele fará com que ele se
> mova para a direita. Muitas vezes, uma imagem é colocada em um
> parágrafo sozinha, mas isso não é obrigatório. Ele pode ter texto
> antes e depois dele no parágrafo em que é colocado.
>
> No momento da escrita, python-docxsuporta apenas imagens em linha.
> Imagens flutuantes podem ser adicionadas. Se você tiver um caso de uso
> ativo, envie uma solicitação de recurso no rastreador de problemas. O
> Document.add_picture()método adiciona uma imagem especificada ao final
> do documento em um parágrafo próprio. No entanto, cavando um pouco
> mais fundo na API, você pode colocar texto em ambos os lados da imagem
> em seu parágrafo, ou em ambos.
> <sub>Fonte: [documentação do python-docx 0.8.11](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/shapes.html#understanding-pictures-and-other-shapes)</sub>

Como visto na documentação se adicionar diretamente uma imagem a um documento essa imagem será adicionada ao final do documento e como a lib não dá suporte a imagens flutuantes essas não podem ser reposicionadas gerando então o comportamento que não quer que ocorra.

Uma solução é manipular os parágrafos e inserir suas imagens dentro dum objeto run:

1. O [objeto parágrafo](http://officeopenxml.com/WPparagraph.php) é o container principal em nível de bloco para conteúdo em um documento ooxml.
2. O [objeto run](http://officeopenxml.com/WPtext.php) reside dentro dum paragrafo como um conjunto de objetos contendo propriedades em comum.

Use os métodos:

- [`Document.add_paragraph()`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#docx.document.Document.add_paragraph) para adicionar um paragrafo ao documento.
- [Paragraph.add_run()](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph.add_run) para adicionar um run a um paragrafo.
- [Run.add_picture()](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.run.Run.add_picture) para adicionar uma imagem ao respectivo run.

Usando como exemplo essas quatro imagens([img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBHJU.jpg), [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QNBV.jpg), [img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ES8D.jpg), [img4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJGnl.jpg)) e traduzindo isso em código:

```python
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches                   #O módulo só foi utilizado para fazer escalonamento das imagens para que caibam num mesmo parágrafo. 

document = Document()

paragraph = document.add_paragraph()             #Cria um novo parágrafo.
run = paragraph.add_run()                        #Adiciona um run ao parágrafo.

run.add_picture("dog1.jpg", width=Inches(1.25))  #Adiciona varias imagens ao parágrafo...
run.add_picture("dog2.jpg", width=Inches(1.25)) 
run.add_picture("dog3.jpg", width=Inches(1.25)) 
run.add_picture("dog4.jpg", width=Inches(1.25)) 
        
document.save('demonstracao.docx')               #Salva o arquivo docx.
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Replit](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/Dogs#main.py)</sup>

Resultando no documento:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Incrível Augusto, muito obrigado mesmo e que papai do céu abençoe!